# What is the simplified boolean expression for A+A`B`?

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

I understand that

> A+A`B=A+B

But what happens when

> B

is replaced by

> B`

on LHS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `A + A'B` is equivalent to `A + B` is because the `A'` is superfluous given the `A +` preceding it. If `A'` weren't already true then `A` would be so the `A +` would already make everything true. *Anything* could follow `A'` in the second part and the answer would be `A +` the rest. In your case, `A + A'B'` is equivalent to `A + B'`. We can verify with a truth table:

```
A    B    A'    B'     A'B'    A + A'B'    A + B'
T    T    F     F      F       T           T
T    F    F     T      F       T           T
F    T    T     F      F       F           F
F    F    T     T      T       T           T
```

Because `A + A'B'` and `A + B'` have the same values for all possible inputs, they are equivalent.